# Static variable changes between different scripts in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

I have a variable called gethealth in two different scripts in Unity. I created it in the first script called PlayerController as a static public float. When I try to access it from the other script(called Health), it displays something completely different, even though it should be the same variable.

I checked that it is the same by using debug.log in both scripts, and somehow it displays something different. Somewhere along the way, it must have changed.

First Script(PlayerController class, where I create and set the gethealth variable):

```
public float health = 250f;
static public float gethealth;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    PlayerLaser missile = col.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerLaser>();
    if (missile)
    {
        health -= missile.GetDamage();
        gethealth = health;
        Debug.Log(gethealth);
        missile.Hit();
    }
}
```

Second Script(Health class):

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log(PlayerController.gethealth);
    Text myText = GetComponent<Text>();
    myText.text = PlayerController.gethealth.ToString();
}
```

The two debug.logs show different results, while they should be showing the same

Comment: As an aside, using `static` this way is not a good idea. You should get a reference to your player script (e.g. `GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>()`) and get its public `health` value that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask why it displays something different, but the code you've provided shows us that it should display something different. On the Health Class you're logging `PlayerController.gethealth` on Start. (See for documentation on the start method: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html)

On PlayerController you're logging `gethealth` after reducing your health and reassigning it.

Unless there is some part of your code missing what should happen is that the `Health` class logs a 0, the default value for a float. After that the PlayerController logs a number less than 250 (250 - `missile.GetDamage()`). This logging happens every time there is call on `OnTriggerEnter2D`, reducing the number being displayed.

What you probably want is to setup the `gethealth` attribute at the Awake method (see previous documentation link) such that

```
Awake() { gethealth = health; }
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me fix it. I went with the update function instead of Awake, and itnitialized the float in Health so that it doesnt log 0.